# Is An Operating System an Process ?

Tags: operating-system, system

I wanted to know if an Operating System is a process
I cannot find the correct answer about this problem so maybe over here i will find something that might help me for exam that i have tomorrow.

Waiting for answer ...

Comment: The short answer is no. StackOverflow is not for last minute cramming for an exam, it is to help working programmers with progaming iossues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What underlays an Operating System is a kernel, which is a bunch of low level, routines that manage the memory and other parts of the computer. The kernel has processes and threads that help the kernel accomplish this task.

Thus, the answer to your question is that no, the Operating System is not just one unique process. It is a bunch of processes managed by the kernel that underlay the more abstract concept of what an Operating System is.

Answer (score 0):

Simply process is the program in execution.

*A process is the instance of a computer program that is being executed by one or many threads. It contains the program code and its activity. Depending on the operating system (OS), a process may be made up of multiple threads of execution that execute instructions concurrently.*

Process creation has Four types of events.

Reference: [Operating System lesson](https://osnote.space)